# associated simple products lost when i add new values to configurable attribute

Tags: configurable-product

i added a attribute via installer script and using this as a configurable attribute. Now i have the problem that all associated products (of a configurable) are lost, if i add a new value to this attribute (within the magento backend attribute interface).

this is how i added the attribute:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'colortype', array(
        'type'              => 'varchar',
        'backend'           => '',
        'frontend'          => '',
        'label'             => 'colortype',
        'input'             => 'select',
        'class'             => '',
        'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
        'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible'           => true,
        'required'          => false,
        'user_defined'      => true,
        'default'           => '',
        'searchable'        => false,
        'filterable'        => 1,
        'comparable'        => true,
        'visible_on_front'  => 1,
        'unique'            => false,
        'apply_to'          => '',
        'is_configurable'   => true,
        'option'            => array(
            'values' => array (
                0 => 'Green',
                1 => 'Red',
                2 => 'Blue',
            )
        )
    ));
```

i thought that something went wrong with the way of how i added the attribute. this is why i am tried to update the attribute via script:

```
    $resource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
    $entityTypeId = $resource->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');
    $attributeId = $resource->getAttribute($entityTypeId, 'colortype','attribute_id');

    $resource->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, $attributeId, array(
        'frontend_input' => 'select',
        'backend_type' => 'int',
        'backend_model' => null,
        'attribute_model' => 'catalog/resource_eav_attribute',
        'source_model' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
    ));
```

its really strange: If I look at the simple products attribute, then the value is displayed correctly. but i can not select the simple product as associated product within the configurable product (associated products tab). The only way to avoid this problem is when I assign a different value to the products attribute, save and then re-assigns the correct value and save again.

can someone explain me how i could fix the problem? thanks a lot.